# How to add 'use_desc_for_title = 0' to all wp_list_categories calls?

Tags: plugin-development

My category descriptions are extremely long, so I don't want the descriptions to be used in the title attribute of my category lists. However, WP does this automatically when it outputs the default category widget in the markup.

Is it possible to add a filter in functions.php that assigns the default value for 'use_desc_for_title' to 0? (The default is 1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to figure this out. Much easier than I thought...

```
function my_categories_filter($cat_args){
    $cat_args['title_li'] = '';
    $cat_args['exclude_tree'] = 1;
    $cat_args['exclude'] = 1;
    $cat_args['use_desc_for_title'] = 0;
    return $cat_args;
}

add_filter('widget_categories_args', 'my_categories_filter', 10, 2);
```

Comment: Note that this will only change arguments for widget, not for all `wp_list_category()` calls. I don't see fitting filter for function itself.

Answer (score 0):

I came looking for solution to the same problem. Eventually discovered a very easy solution rather than modifying the function as suggested by Scott B.

It can simply be achieved by using `&use_desc_for_title=0`in the appropriate place where you want to hide the long description of category.

It would look something like

```
<?php wp_list_categories('orderby=id&show_count=1&use_desc_for_title=0'); ?>
```

Comment: I think his particular use case was changing the categories widget settings, rather than a custom call to `wp_list_categories()`;